# Confidence interval of a binomial distribution?

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to use the `Clopper Pearson Interval` for a binomial distribution, but am not sure how to find it, despite having the formula:

[image: Clopper Pearson Interval]

What does this mean exactly (I'm confused by the notation and the intersection of two sets), and how can I find the interval given `n`, the number of trials, `theta`, the probability for success, and a confidence level of 0.95?

Comment: Do you know what [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) is? $\;$

Comment: To some extent, but what I don't quite understand in particular is what it means for these two sets to intersect, or how to get `P[B(n,theta) < X]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set denotes the set of all values for $\theta$ for which the probability that $X$ is at least $Bin(n,\theta)$ is greater than $\frac{\alpha}{2}$. Similarly, the second set consists of all $\theta$ for which the probability that $X$ is at most $Bin(n,\theta)$ is greater than $\frac{\alpha}{2}$. Since we have the intersection of these two sets, the resulting set consists of all $\theta$ for which $P(Bin(n,\theta) \leq X) > \frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $P(Bin(n,\theta) \geq X) > \frac{\alpha}{2}$. This means that $\theta$ is excluded if and only if $P(Bin(n,\theta) \geq X) \leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$ or $P(Bin(n,\theta) \leq X) \leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$. In other words, $\theta$ is excluded if and only if $X$ is too large to approximate by $Bin(n,\theta)$ or if $X$ is too small. If $X \sim Bin(n,\theta)$ there is a $(1-\alpha)$ chance that $\theta$ ends up in the set, thus the given set is a $(1-\alpha)$-confidence interval for $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you, this clears it up a great deal.